# Find a git branch and change it with a windows batch file command

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

Currently in my workspace all git branches are in the format
`feature/FAC-n-description-of-issue` where n is the issue number
So i want to make a `change.bat` file so i can type
`change -f FAC-n` or something like that and switch to that branch. But i don't know how to make the batch file look for a branch that start with feature/FAC-n independently of whats after that. Any thought ?

Comment: Do you have a batch file you've made so far? May you share that?

Comment: Most of this is a matter of writing .BAT files (i.e., programming in the batch language). From the [tag:git] side of this, all we can say is: avoid *porcelain* commands in favor of *plumbing* commands. A Git plumbing command is one designed to be used by other commands, rather than by a human; a Git porcelain command is one designed to be used by humans. For instance, `git branch` is porcelain; `git for-each-ref` is plumbing.